# mysql vs mariadb joins gives different results

Tags: mysql, mariadb

as part of migration from mysql to mariadb, i face a query that gives different results between mysql and mariadb when joining the same table twice to perfrom cross search. for some reason that i can't understand, on mysql the query works perfect but on the mariadb side, the query gives no results

this is my query:

```
    SELECT a.*, c.title as category, c.seperator 
    FROM MainLink 
    LEFT JOIN MainLink AS ArticleLink on ArticleLink.tag_id = MainLink.tag_id 
    LEFT JOIN articles AS a on a.id = ArticleLink.object_id 
    INNER JOIN categories c on a.category_id=c.id 
    WHERE ArticleLink.module_id = '20' AND MainLink.module_id = '12' AND MainLink.object_id = '1625' 
    GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.id DESC
```

MainLink Table:

```
|tag_id|int(10)|UNSIGNED
|module_id|int(10)|UNSIGNED
|object_id|int(10)UNSIGNED
```

articles table:

```
|id|int(10)|UNSIGNED
|title|varchar(1000)|UNSIGNED
|category_id|int(10)|UNSIGNED
```

categories table:

```
|id|int(10)|UNSIGNED
|title|varchar(100)|UNSIGNED
```

Comment: You have a group by with no aggregations so the result is non determinate (and in some shops this query wouldn't syntax).. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @P.Salmon this query not working on the mariadb side even if i remove the group by

Comment: varchar unsigned ?? also c.seperator  does not exist, please take a moment to review your question and make it consistent.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue but if you have no errors and result is no rows returned there is no data which fulfills your joins and/or where conditions. I suggest you debug by removing code until you find the issue.